# How to handle One to Many relationship between entities using Ali Data Table Bundle in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

I am having two entities say "Users" and "UsersMeta". I am using AliDataTable Bundle to show the data from the two tables but I have 1 to Many relationship between the tables. So when I am making join I am getting the result which is right but I do not want it that way.
Suppose the two tables has data as

Users

```
id|firstname|lastname|email
1 |abc      |xyz     |abc@abc.com 
2 |def      |zyx     |def@test.com
```

UsersMeta

```
Meta_id|User_id|fieldname|fieldValue
      1|1      |dob      |ddd
      2|1      |gender   |ggg
      3|2      |dob      |ddd2
      4|2      |gender   |ggg2
```

I am getting the listing using AliDataTable as

```
Firstname|lastname|Email       |Fieldname|Fieldvalue
      abc|xyz     |abc@test.com|dob      |ddd
      abc|xyz     |abc@test.com|gender   |ggg
      def|zyx     |def@test.com|dob      |ddd2
      def|zyx     |def@test.com|gender   |ggg2
```

Mine sample code for AliDataTable configuration is as follows

```
private function _DataTable()
{
    $controller_instance = $this;
    $datatable = $this->get('datatable');
    return $datatable->setEntity("xxx\Entity\ User ", "u")                          
                ->setFields(
                        array(
                            "First Name"      => 'u.firstName',     
                            "Last Name"       => 'u.lastName',
                            "Email"           => 'u.email',
                           "FieldName"        => 'um.fieldName',
                            "FieldValue"      => 'um.fieldValue',
                            "_identifier_"    => 'u.userId')                    
                        )
                ->addJoin('u. UsersMeta', 'um', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::INNER_JOIN)
                ->setWhere(                                                     
                    'u.userId = um.userId
                )

                })

                ->setHasAction(true);                                           
}
```

I want data to be displayed as like

```
Firstname|lastname|Email       |dob      |gender
      abc|xyz     |abc@test.com|ddd      |ggg
      def|zyx     |def@test.com|ddd2     |ggg2
```

So, How can I obtain the data in above format using AliDataTable bundle ? I have read that we can customize the rendering of the field value but in above case I need to change the render of the table. I do not know whether this is possible or not since I just started to work in Symfony2. Please suggest.